# Running a t-test on different (sub?)sets [survey logic]

Tags: survey

This might be a better fit in the Mathematics or Philosophy StackExchanges, as I think I'm fundamentally facing a problem of logic, but I'll throw it out here first to avoid cross-posting.

I have two surveys - Survey A and Survey B. I want to validate Survey A's findings against Survey B's.

I have one indicator: average meals eaten per day in the household.

Survey A divides the question into two sub-questions:

1. Daily average household meals
2. Daily average meals for children (aged 6 months to 5 years)

Now, (1) could be a superset of (2), but not necessarily. Kids might eat with their parents, and thus as much as their parents. Kids might eat less than their parents. Kids might eat more - say, if parents give up a meal in order to feed their kid. Some households might not have kids. So I imagine it as a Venn diagram, where the little "kids" bubble overlaps (a lot) with the big "household" bubble, but might not be completely subsumed by it.

Survey B, instead, divides this into three sub-questions:

1. Daily average meals for adults
2. Daily average meals for children (aged 6 months to 5 years)
3. Daily average meals for children (aged 5 years to 13 years)

Here, it seems cleaner. These are three distinct groups (ignoring, for now, the fact that both (2) and (3) could capture 5 year olds).

I'd like to run t-tests on the survey means of, say, daily average meals for the household, and daily average meals for children (6 months - 5 years). But I'm not sure how I can combine and disentangle these different sets from each other to make them comparable.

Comment: The 2 questions numbered 2 in both surveys are identical.  Is there a reason you are concerned that comparing the means for these 2 questions might be misleading or inappropriate in some way?  (I see no other comparison that is logically clean.)

Comment: Thanks, Joel. You're right, in that I could compare those. However, is there anything I can do with the other(s) (relating to total-household or adults-only)? Something to compare is better than nothing, but more would also be better.

Comment: The best you could do if you make comparisions of the first questions of each survey is to tell the reader that the comparision is inexact because the questions are worded differently.